# Pivot tables: How can I total the subtotal?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function, pivot-table

My `SUBTOTA`L row shows Person A needs £115, `Person D` £234 and `Person G` £789, but how do I `SUM` those totals and get it to show the total on the same ROW?

The Rows are subscription names.

The Value field holds the Cost per subscription.

the Columns holds the name of the person who receives the subscription.

I have `GROUPED` on `YEAR` & `MONTH`, and have a `SUBTOTAL` that shows me how much each person will need to pay each month for all their subscriptions, but I need a figure showing me the total of all the subscriptions per month.

I've tried adding calculated fields, but I want to SUM the subtotals so I'm struggling to see the field I need to use. I've tried Grand Totals but that `SUMS` all rows and I really only want `SUM` the Subtotal Total Row.

I need a nice neat report that my managers won't go white at when looking at it...to many numbers = fear and confusion.

Anyway it got messy, so I've come for help.

> **UPDATE**: I've found a way. It's not perfect but it'll do: 
>   use GRAND TOTALS for ROWS, and then format the totals you do not want to see in white
>
> Like I said, it's not perfect but it'll do. How do I close this post?

Cheers

Mike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way. It's not perfect but it'll do: use GRAND TOTALS for ROWS, and then format the totals you do not want to see in white

Like I said, it's not perfect but it'll do. How do I close this post?

Comment: You don't need to close this post. If this answer is OK for you, just accept it as your own answer.